# Filtering objects in Django using foreign keys as parameters

Tags: python, django, filter

I'm working with the Django tutorial that helps you build a Poll application. I finished all the tutorials and now I´m trying to add some extra features to learn more about django.

I have 2 models `Poll` and `Choice`. The model Choice has a foreign key to Polls, so I can have several choices on each poll. What I want to do is to filter the polls that are shown on my index page by removing those that don´t have any choice at all. I think I can do that with the get_queryset method, but I´m not sure how to use the filter method to accomplish this. Can anyone help me with this?

My Models:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models
import datetime



from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
# Create your models here.

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
    return self.question

def was_published_recently(self):
    now = timezone.now()
    return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <  now


was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
was_published_recently.boolean = True
was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'

class Choice(models.Model):
   poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
   choice_text = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
   votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
    return self.choice_text
```

My Index view

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
template_name = 'polls/index.html'
context_object_name = 'latest_poll_list'

def get_queryset(self):
    """
    Return the last five published polls (not including those set to be
    published in the future) and remove polls with no choices.
    """
    # Removing Polls with no Choices

    #Filtering by recent posts (just one day old)
    p= Poll.objects.filter(
        pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
    ).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    return p
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is [annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset):

```
from django.db.models import Count

polls_with_choices = Poll.objects.annotate(num_choices=Count('choice'))
                                 .filter(num_choices__gt=0)
```

Essentially, the 'annotate' queryset method will generate SQL that adds a computed column to the results of the query. You then filter on the contents of that computed column.

Comment: Thanks fow Answering. I tried your solution too, but I´m also getting the same error:

Cannot resolve keyword 'choices' into field. Choices are: choice, id, pub_date, question

Any idea  how to solve this? Thanks again.

Comment: Changed the line to this: Poll.objects.annotate(num_choices=Count('choice_set')).filter(choices_count__gt=0)

but getting the same error : Cannot resolve keyword 'choice_set' into field. Choices are: choice, id, pub_date, question

Comment: It says an option is 'choice', have you tried that?

Comment: Yes I´ve tried that too, also tried with id. It show no errors, but it does not filter out a poll I created with no choices.

Comment: I´ve solved it Thanks :) I was undoing the filter with the line below that filters the polls from recent dates.

Comment: I edited the answer to make sure it's correct. Is it accurate for what worked for you?

Answer (score 2):

You're right to use the `get_queryset` method for this. You can exclude any results where there are no choices like this:

```
p = Poll.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now(), choices__isnull=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried your code but I got this error:
Cannot resolve keyword 'Choices' into field. Choices are: choice, id, pub_date, question

Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: Damn those default names. I always get confused, that's why I always specify the `related_name`, e.g. if you use `poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll, related_name='choices')`, you can access the choices with `poll.choices`.

Comment: Thanks that´s a good practice for foreign keys. I´ll change the related name to 'choices'